# Chart.js and Firebase Ionic App Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have this method which gets data from firebase and then stores it in an array. When I console.log() the array it all looks good. However, I'm not sure how to store it in the labels and data of the Chart.js.

Home.ts get data method

```
  getData() {
   var x = [];
   var y = [];
   this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
   if (user) { this.userId = user.uid }
   let items = firebase.database().ref(`completed/${user.uid}/${this.year}`).orderByKey();
  items.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      x.push(key);
      y.push(childData);
    });
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  });
 });
}
```

The console.log at the bottom returns ["Jan","Feb","March"] which is exactly what I want. However, I'm not sure how to store them in the chart.

I know that you can use this, but I cant get it to work.

```
this.lineChart.data.labels
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to assign labels before you actually get it from firebase ?

I was using dynamic labels for chart js and was simply passing data as function argument and there shouldn't be problem for you as well

Below is glimpse of my code

```
function bar_graph_instance(element, answers, answers_count){
  Chart.defaults.global.elements.responsive = false;
  var ctx = document.getElementById(element);
  ctx.height = 400;
  return new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: answers,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Total Answers",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(64,202,100, 0.6)",
              data: answers_count
            }
          ]
        },
```